# Why is this contact form not working?

Tags: php, forms

It seems everything is in place:
**PHP:**

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['name'])){
$msg = "name". $_POST['name'];
}else{
$fname = NULL;
echo "Name Required.<br />";
}

if (!empty($_POST['email'])){
$msg = "email". $_POST['email'];
}else{
$lname = NULL;
echo "Email Required.<br />";
}

if (!empty($_POST['www'])){
$msg = "Website". $_POST['www'];
}else{
$lname = NULL;
echo "Website Required.<br />";
}

if (!empty($_POST['comment'])){
$msg = "Comment". $_POST['comment'];
}else{
$email = NULL;
echo "A comment is required.<br />";
}

$recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Form Feedback";
$mailheaders = "Reply-to". $_POST['email'];
//send the mail
mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contact" style="height:280px; margin:1px 0;">
    <form id="contactLP" method="post" action="inc/php/contact_validate.php">
            <div class="align"><input type="text" name="name" tabindex="1" /></div>
            <div class="align"><input type="text" name="email" tabindex="2" /></div>
            <div class="align"><input type="text" name="www" tabindex="3" /></div>
            <div class="align"><textarea id="txta" name="comment" cols="15" rows="5" tabindex="4"></textarea></div>
            <span style="color:transparent;">test</span>
            <br><br>
        <div class="align"><input type="submit" class="submit" name="sendForm" id="SubmitContact" value="" tabindex="5" /></div>
    </form>
</div><!--CONTACT-->
```

When I fill it out correctly and submit, it says "Thanks for your message" or something similiar, but then I get nothing in email.

I tried running this both on a server on the internet, along with on my local server running on my workstation.

Am I doing something wrong above???????

Comment: Please try to isolate the problem.  If you write a script that simply sends an email (with none of the form stuff), does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are  `"name; $_POST['name'] ";` should be  `"name". $_POST['name'];` in every instance you use that string.

Comment: So your saying for website, email, comment it needs to be this same way?

Comment: `'Reply-To: '`. not `'Reply-to'`  and you need `$msg .=`

Answer (score 1):

Your $msg is only holding the current value.

Try something like this for all your value assignment to $msg variable

```
$msg .= "Comment". $_POST['comment'];
```

Answer (score 0):

[mail function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

You seem to have screwed up the $mailheaders variable slightly (reply-to section), try this code in a stand alone script. If even it fails, you may have to check your mail function and how it is set up on the server. (change the email addresses obviously)

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```